# Call Python class in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, python

How can I call python class in JMeter to test the performance of the python code as we do in java by importing jar file and write a script in BeanShell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512365/jmeter-run-a-python-script-before-calling-each-http-request-sampler

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you should go for combination of [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) and [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) as JMeter is a **Java** based application and it is "alien" for python.

---

If you still want to do this using JMeter:

1. You can add [Jython](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) library to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and once you restart JMeter you will get possibility to use `python` language in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

   [image: JMeter Python from scripts]
2. JMeter comes with [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) so you should be able to kick off your Python function in multiple threads and measure time taken

   [image: JMeter Execute Python]

   You will also be able to work with command output if needed:

   [image: JMeter Python Execute OS Process Sampler]